# Proof of $W=M_{n}(R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n$ be an integer $\ge 2$ and let $M_{n}(R)$ denotes the vector spaces of $n\times n$ real matrices. Let, $B\in M_{n}(R)$ be an orthogonal matrix & let $B^{T}$ be the transpose of $B$. Consider $$W=\{B^{T}AB:A\in M_{n}(R)\}.$$

Then prove that, $W=M_{n}(R)$.

Clearly $W$ is a subspace of $M_{n}(R)$. Now it is sufficient to show that $M_{n}(R)\subset W$. To show it, we take any matrix $M\in M_{n}(R)$. Now $M\in W$ if $M$ can be expressed in the form $B^{T}AB$ for some matrix $A\in M_{n}(R)$, where $B$ is orthogonal & $A\in M_{n}(R)$. Since, $B$ is orthogonal, so $B^{T}=B^{-1}$.

$i.e.$ $M$ can be expressed in the form $B^{-1}AB$ (where, clearly $B$ is invertible, as $B$ is orthogonal, $det(B)=\pm 1$) & it is possible if and only if $M$ is diagonalizable.

But $M$ is arbitrary matrix in $M_{n}(R)$,so it may or may not be diagonalizable.

From here how I can proceed to prove the result or any other way to complete the proof.

Please Help.

Comment: You made a mistake: $M=B^{-1}AB$, then $M$ is diagonalizable if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable. Anyway, as $B$ is invertible, you should be able to find an inverse map of the map $A\mapsto B^{-1}AB$.

Comment: You can ultimately show that conjugation by an invertible matrix (in this case, $B^TAB$ for a orthogonal matrix $B$ is a special case) is a ring automorphism of $M_n(R)$. Doing this, it will send the ideal $M_n(R)$ to the ideal $M_n(R)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every matrix $M$ satisfies

$M=B^{-1}(BMB^{-1})B.$

That is, the matrix $A$ you are looking for is $BMB^{-1}=BMB^T.$

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$\Phi: \mathcal M_n(\Bbb R)\to\mathcal M_n(\Bbb R),\quad A\mapsto B^TAB$$
We have easily $\Phi$ is a linear transformation and the equation $\Phi(A)=C$ has a unique solution:

$$B^TAB=C\iff A=BCB^T$$
hence $\Phi$ is an automorphism of vector space and the result follows.